# Iterating through and modifying DOM elements added via Ajax without jQuery

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mutation-observers

I'm working on a small Firefox Addon that uses `PageMod` to process image elements loaded in a web page. I've seen examples on the web that used jQuery but since I'm adding a content script to every webpage, adding jQuery might cause irreparable damage.

Since Firefox supports `MutationObserver` I have tried to do the following thanks to [AndrewVermie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973214/andrew-vermie) :

**content.js**

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

    if(mutation.tagName == "IMG")
    {
        //I'm not sure this object can be treated as a DOM Element (?)
        mutation.src = "http://s6.tinypic.com/15npphk_th.jpg";
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; ++i) {
          var node = mutation.addedNodes[i],
              matches = [].slice.call(node.querySelectorAll('img'));

          for (var j = 0; j < matches.length; ++j) {
              var img = matches[j];
              img.src = "http://s6.tinypic.com/15npphk_th.jpg";
          }
      }
   });
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true};
observer.observe(window.document, config);


var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var elementsLength = elements.length;
for (var i = 0; i < elementsLength; i++) 
{
    elements[i].src = "http://s6.tinypic.com/15npphk_th.jpg";
}
```

**main.js**

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("content.js")],
    onAttach: //...
    }
});
```

**What happens :**

1. Go to http://imgur.com/
2. Start scrolling until images are loaded dynamically
3. Notice that they are not changing

I `console.log()` every `.tagName` and only see `p` and `#text` when I hover over images.

**What I need**

Iterate through each element loaded dynamically within a webpage in which the script is injected and be able to modify the element's attributes.

If it can be done with pure JavaScript and with or without `MutationObserver` that'll be really swell.

Otherwise, if I can find out just that some elements have been loaded to reiterate through ALL the elements of the page again, that'll be OK but not swell.

I hope I've cleared things up a bit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. As it is right now, your requirements are far too unspecific, and I cannot do not even understand what *exactly* you're trying to achieve.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvermie/Dfdf2/1/) is able to do what you want; does it work for you from the fiddle, but not from the addon?

Comment: @AndrewVermie I'll test this right away.

Comment: @AndrewVermie It doesn't work from the addon. I'll provide the code from your example as a test case for nmaier's request.

Comment: @nmaier I have cleared things up a bit I hope. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake here is to think that all nodes actually have a `querySelectorAll` method. E.g. text nodes do not!
So you called a non-existent method, which threw an exception and ended your processing early (as the first mutation node on imgur.com is actually a text node).

Here is what I came up with, what seems to do what you're after, ecma-6-ified a bit :p. My content script:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  for (var m of mutations) {
    for (var node of m.addedNodes) {
      if (!node || !node.querySelectorAll) {
        // Not all nodes support querySelectorAll, e.g. text nodes.
        continue;
      }
      for (var img of node.querySelectorAll("img")) {
        img.src = "http://s6.tinypic.com/15npphk_th.jpg";
      }
    }
  }
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true};
observer.observe(window.document, config);

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var elementsLength = elements.length;
for (var i = 0; i < elementsLength; i++) {
    elements[i].src = "http://s6.tinypic.com/15npphk_th.jpg";
}
```

Comment: It worked very well. Thank you very much. Twice in the same day :)

Comment: Just a note: As you already use ECMA 6 features I would use `let` instead of `var` for the _loops_ or  write `var` at one place, so that it is clear at the first look which vars are bound to the scope ( [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) )

Comment: @t.niese Thank you. I have a C/C++ systems programming background and I'm not well versed in these matters. nmaier and yourself provided some very important clarifications for me. Can any of you suggest some recommended reading (other that the MDN docs) so I can avoid these types of mistakes in the future?

Comment: When I look for this type of information I usually run into jQuery or how to make webpage text blink which is less than useful.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc: currently I don't have. Douglas Crockford tends to have good explanations and probably watching this video: [YouTube: Douglas Crockford - JavaScript, The World's Most Misunderstood Language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gz7KL7ZirZc) is a good starting point to get a rough feeling where problems are. But generally things like: `scope`, `closures`, `var hoisting`, `Promise`, `requirejs/adm` and the `async` behavior of many libraries are things you should know.